# Laptop won't turn on

Tags: laptop, battery, power

My friend got a really bad virus on the computer and it set a BIOS password, somehow? Or set it without knowing and can't remember the password, so I took the laptop apart and took out the bios battery for 24 hrs.

After, I put the laptop back together plugged it in, and it was working.

I turned the laptop of, and now it won't turn back on?

There are no lights flashing or showing when I try to turn the laptop on. If I plug the mains into the laptop, the charging light comes on but I still can't turn it on, and again no lights are flashing.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: laptop make/model?

Comment: Acer aspire 2920

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible the power switch was damaged or the case was not reassembled correctly?
Try taking it apart again, and try powering it on directly from the motherboard, or switch behind the casing.

Comment: The laptop turned on and was working fine when then I turned it off it didn't turn back on again.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume the laptop (for some reason) won't start without the CMOS battery. It's very likely you drained it when removing it; all you need to do is touch both sides at once and they empty almost instantly.

Try to find a replacement battery. Certainly going to be one of the safer/cheaper things to try.

Comment: But the battery worked when I put it back in, as I said it booted up fine once and then stopped all of a sudden. I didn't leave it on charge for very long after I put it back in, is it possible that this damaged the CMOS battery?

Comment: Unlikely; I don't think the batteries are rechargeable. Wait, all of a sudden? Did laptop stop suddenly, or did it shutdown fine (as stated in question)?

Comment: When I turned the laptop on, i went onto the BIOS to see if it worked, then tried some backdoor passwords, so the system halted. I then held down the power button to turn it off.